# generate the same random number for 2 arrays in js function

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript :

```
    function itemNumber() {
      var arrayOne = new Array('first', 'second', third);
      var arrayTwo = new Array('1', '2', '3');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='items'>
   <h1 id='words'>first</h1>
   <h1 id='numbers'>1</h1>
</div>
```

I want when refreshed thinks to look like first 1 or second 2 or third 3.
Not like first 3, second 1.

Comment: Generate the index randomly (there are many, many answers for that on SO), then use that for both arrays.

Comment: [using-the-same-random-number-in-multiple-places-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710108/using-the-same-random-number-in-multiple-places-javascript)